# Can you say "at speed"?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm trying to make a tagline for my website, can I say "download files **at** super fast **speeds**"? Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Related, [Roses are red, bananas are yellow](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/roses-are-red-apples-are-green)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Many speeds are recorded *at* (plus something)

"The Hong Kong Observatory put the storm's maximum ten-minute sustained winds at 260 km/h (160 mph) prior to landfall in the central ". (Wiki)

"She types at (a speed of) 56 words per minute."

A child's vocabulary grows at an average rate of (however many words per year depending on age.)

I won't go into 'at vs of', I will just say that for your purpose, your word choice is fine.

Comment: Thanks Susan, this a great explanation. Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say it, and it is idiomatic (though I would write *superfast* as one word).

Answer (score 1):

Another use of 'at speed' might be:

```
The crash happened at speed.
```

meaning the crash happened while (the car) was travelling at a significant speed. i.e. not while stationary or when maneuvering.